# SSH / TLS support for midnight commander?

Tags: ssh, ftp, tls

Does anyone know if Midnight Commander could support FTP over TLS / SSH?

One of our clients use Midnight Commander and we since we recently switch to explicit FTP over TLS (for security reasons) she can't connect to the server anymore.

Does anyone know if there's a way to configure Midnight Commander to use FTP over TLS, or SSH?

Answer (score 3):

Launch Midnight Commander, type

```
cd ssh://user@hostname
```

Comment: It is "sh" not "ssh", at least on debian 7.

Answer (score 3):

FTPS is currently unsupported.

I've created an issue for this:
https://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/3343

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [FUSE](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) and [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) or [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 2):

`mc` supports "Shell links" in the respective "side menu". This uses `ssh` to establish a `fish` connection (***FI**le transfer over **SH**ell filesystem*).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I believe that shell links are based on SFTP, not on FTPS.

Answer (score -1):

select the left or right menu... SFTP link...